# Использование gotoxy и delay

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Как использовать в Visual c++ `gotoxy` и `delay`?

Answer (score 1):

Под `Visual C++` существует своя имплементация стандартных функций `BGI` под названием [**WinBGI**.](http://csci.biola.edu/csci105/graphics.html)

Соответственно, все что вам нужно сделать - это подключить соответствующие файлы в свой проект и использовать уже привычные функции `Turbo C`.

Comment: Без .NET видимо не работает ? 

Попробовал минут 15 и бросил. А вообще интересно. Можно еще поискать какую-нибудь реализацию Ncurses для Windows.

Comment: @avp Не, там код на `WinAPI`, так что без `.NET` тоже будет работать. Просто автор видимо неправильно понимает название `Visual Studio`.

Comment: Это хорошо, если будет желание, попробую найти \*.h и библиотеки, которые надо подсоединять. 

Можно будет попробовать перевести это под чистый Си (без ++).

Comment: я новичек,
и когда написал на borland c++ 3.1
попробовал на Visual c++ 
для delay нужен dos.h но visual c++ пишет ошибку

Comment: Про Visual c++ к сожалению помочь не смогу (не знаю), я использую MinGW. У меня dos.h лежит в C:\\MinGW\\include

@Котик\_хочет\_кушать, собрал Вашу штуку (g++) правда с warnings и getch() после ее инициализации странно работает (читает из созданного окошка, а не с консоли), но если вдуматься так и должно быть.

Кстати, какой-нибудь ник покороче не хотите ? (например neko - по Японски).